# How to filter out a value from joint table in MySQl?

Tags: mysql

Hi I have a table t1 and a second table t2. When a user interacts with something in t1 it gets added to t2. Now I want to get all rows from t1 that both don't exist in t2 and does not have 1 in t2.c3.

My attempts so far have not been able to get rows that don't exist in t2.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.c1 FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2
    ON t1.c1 = t2.c2
    AND t2.c1=$user_click
    WHERE t2.c3 != 1
```

Example:

```
  t1:
'John'
'Doe'
'Smith'
'Casablanca'
```

After clicking on Casablanca it gets inserted in t2.

```
  t2:
'Casablanca' | NULL
```

Only Casablanca is selected now because those in t1 don't have NULL. I want all of the rows to show up until I change Casablanca to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Sorry, I misread what you were expecting and forgot Outers aren't a thing in MySQL and completely unnecessary in this instance. Truth be told your query was fine, just missing one param. Given the table structure below:

t1:

c1 | c2

t2:

c1 | c2 | c3

Where c1 = PK, c2 = name and c3 = isInteracted

This query should get what you want:

```
SELECT t1.c1, t2.c1, t2.c3 FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 on t1.c1 = t2.c1
WHERE t2.c3 IS NULL or t2.c3 <> 1
```

Comment: There isn't a FULL outer join in mysql.

Comment: Aye. I was dead tired and thinking you're looking for NULLs in both tables, completely ignore previous response, I've edited the answer to better reflect what you need. The user above beat me to it though.

Answer (score 0):

Beware of nulls and code for them

```
drop table if exists t1,t2;
create table t1 (id varchar(20));
insert into t1 values
('John'),
('Doe'),
('Smith'),
('Casablanca');
create table t2  (id varchar(20) ,col3 varchar(20));
insert into t2 values
('Casablanca' , NULL);

SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2     ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id is null or ifnull(t2.col3,0) <>  1
```

Result

```
+------------+------------+------+
| id         | id         | col3 |
+------------+------------+------+
| Casablanca | Casablanca | NULL |
| John       | NULL       | NULL |
| Doe        | NULL       | NULL |
| Smith      | NULL       | NULL |
+------------+------------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```